# How to orient a block in 1.13 with setblock

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

If I wanted to fill an area with jungle logs facing a certain way, in 1.12 it would be:

```
fill -330 73 -63 -330 73 -70 log 11
```

I assumed for 1.13 it would be:

```
fill -330 73 -63 -330 73 -70 minecraft:jungle_log{rotation:3}
```

or something to that effect, but I don't know what the tag is and afaik it's not listed anywhere on any wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Blockstates](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block_states) are how you'd do this. They're specified after the block ID, in a `[key=value,key=value]` format. For example:

```
fill -330 73 -63 -330 73 -70 jungle_log[axis=x]
```

You can find a block's blockstates on the F3 screen when looking at it:

[image: F3 targeted block]

Or, 1.13's command suggestions/completions can be helpful:

[image: Tab-complete blockstates]